# Flattening layers of DIVs and SVG into a single image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, coldfusion

I'm working on a ball customizer for a client.  It allows the viewer to change the colors of the ball, change the text, etc.  The ball itself is just many layers of `div`s stacked on top of each other with their background image changing to predefined colors.  The SVG comes in when they want to change the text of the ball (I use SVG because the text needs to curve).

The problem arises when I try to use `toDataURL`.  I guess the SVG in the canvas basically ruins it from ever being able to pass through `toDataURL` without the browser throwing a security warning.

What are my other options?  The backend is ColdFusion.

Comment: One option could be to load SVG through Fabric.js then use toDataURL. It could be an overkill though (since you'll need ~80KB of extra JS code that Fabric is; but it will take care of SVG parsing and rendering it onto canvas).

Answer (score 0):

you can render svg to image by putting it in blob, you can also render html to svg using xhtml namespace - security error is caused by svg namespace property (xmlns) in  tag as www.w3.org/2000/svg is "cross origin" (for me its just Chrome bug). If you really need do get pixel data from client side generated svg - you may be in trouble i'm not sure if it's possible at all to make it works in chrome. I'd rather try to render curved text directly on canvas, not svg

Comment: Certain use of svg in canvas has been fixed recently, see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119492.